# Cucumber cannot generate tests for scenario outline

Tags: java, cucumber, gherkin, cucumber-java

I'm currently writing some tests usig cucumber, and I would like to use scenario outlines. However, I did not manage to make them work, as cucumber simply cannot generate the test bodies properly.

An example from official gherkin dokumentation https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/

```
Scenario Outline: eating
  Given there are <start> cucumbers
  When I eat <eat> cucumbers
  Then I should have <left> cucumbers

  Examples:
    | start | eat | left |
    |    12 |   5 |    7 |
    |    20 |   5 |   15 |
```

What cucumber generated:

```
public class SomeFeature { 
    @Given("there are <start> cucumbers") 
    public void thereAreStartCucumbers() { 
    }
    
    @When("I eat <eat> cucumbers")
    public void iEatEatCucumbers() {
    }
    
    @Then("I should have <left> cucumbers")
    public void iShouldHaveLeftCucumbers() {
    }
}
```

No arguments in any of the functions, and moreover, in .feature file the lines are still marked as undefined step references.

I tried to write something similar at first, didn't work either:

```
Feature: Test a numbers addition 
    Scenario Outline: Java can add numbers properly 
        When <add1> gets added to <add2> 
        Then expect the result to be <sum>

        Examples:
          | add1 | add2 | sum |
          | 2    | 2    | 4   |
          | 4    | 5    | 9   |

public class MyStepdefs { 
    @When("<add{int}> gets added to <add{int}>") 
    public void addGetsAddedToAdd(int arg0, int arg1) { 
    }
    
    @Then("expect the result to be <sum>")
    public void expectTheResultToBeSum() {
    }
```

No clue why that happens - usual scenarios are being generated and run by me perfectly, but scenario outlines seem to be broken.

My pom:

```
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
      <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
      <groupId>au.com.dius.pact.provider</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit5spring</artifactId>
      <version>${pact.version}</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
      <groupId>au.com.dius.pact.provider</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit5</artifactId>
      <version>${pact.version}</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
      <groupId>au.com.dius.pact.consumer</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit5</artifactId>
      <version>${pact.version}</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId> <!-- zum senden von Requests an den Mock-Server -->
      <artifactId>httpclient5</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.3</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.3</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>${logback.version}</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
      <version>${logback.version}</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
      <version>7.8.1</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
      <version>7.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <version>4.4.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
      <artifactId>wiremock-jre8-standalone</artifactId>
      <version>2.31.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-platform-suite</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
      <version>5.6.6</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
      <version>5.6.6</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
      <artifactId>surefire-junit-platform</artifactId>
      <version>2.22.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
      <version>7.2.3</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
         <configuration>
            <properties>
               <configurationParameters>
                  cucumber.junit-platform.naming-strategy=long
               </configurationParameters>
            </properties>
            <includes>
               <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
               <include>**/*TestRunner.java</include>
               <include>**/*MyStepDefs.java</include>
            </includes>
         </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
         <groupId>au.com.dius.pact.provider</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven</artifactId>
         <version>${pact.version}</version>
         <configuration>
            <pactDirectory>${project.build.directory}/pacts</pactDirectory>
            <pactBrokerUrl>http://pact.datev.de</pactBrokerUrl>
            <projectVersion>${project.version}</projectVersion>
            <tags>
               <!--suppress UnresolvedMavenProperty -->
               <tag>${pact.tag}</tag>
            </tags>
         </configuration>
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not using Cucumber to generate your step definitions but rather InteliJ IDEA. You should create a bug report on their issue tracker.

Now your setup looks more complicated then it should be. At a glance you are not following Maven conventions w.r.t test names, mixing different versions of Cucumber, adding test execution plugins as test dependencies, ect, ect, ect.

You may want to start over with the https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton so you've got the bare minimum example that works.

When you use this, and you run your tests either with `mvn test` or by running the `RunCucumberTest` class through IDEA you should see:

```
The step 'there are 12 cucumbers' and 2 other step(s) are undefined.
You can implement these steps using the snippet(s) below:

@Given("there are {int} cucumbers")
public void there_are_cucumbers(Integer int1) {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();
}
@When("I eat {int} cucumbers")
public void i_eat_cucumbers(Integer int1) {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();
}
@Then("I should have {int} cucumbers")
public void i_should_have_cucumbers(Integer int1) {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();
}
```